# C# Pattern Match result differs from non-pattern syntax

Tags: c#, resharper, c#-9.0

I cannot grasp why these two checks produce different results:

```
int i = -1;
var isValid1 = char.MinValue <= i && i <= char.MaxValue; // This produces 'false' as expected
var isValid2 = i is <= char.MinValue and <= char.MaxValue; // This produces 'true'. WTF?
```

For reference `char.MinValue` is `0`, and `char.MaxValue` is `65535`.

ReSharper suggested that I re-wrote line 2 to the syntax of line 3, but at runtime they produce different results. Can anyone explain why the two lines produce different results? Logically they look the same to me...

EDIT:
Is it because ReSharper rewrote it wrong? I.e. line 3 should have been rewritten as:

```
var isValid2 = i is >= char.MinValue and <= char.MaxValue;
```

?

Comment: You have a typo: `i is <= char.MinValue` should be `i is >= char.MinValue`. Then everything works as expected.

Comment: Omg. Thanks ReSharper for rewriting it wrong...

Comment: If the issue can be reproduced, I'm sure ReSharper will appreciate a bug report. Just make sure you are using the lastest version, because it might have been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Although this is entirely subjective, I think this is a pretty good case against refactoring it to the new syntax, which to me is definitely not more clear than the straightforward conditional. If `i` were a more elaborate expression and not just a single variable it might be different.

Comment: Yup. Bug reported. Can be reproduced in latest and greatest v. 2021.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the report! The problem will be fixed in the first pre-release build 2021.2 EAP1, which we are going to release in a few weeks. Here is YouTrack ticket about this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-483825. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Awesome, many thanks for very quick response Mary! Somewhat 'glad' that software engineers as great as JetBrains can also make small silly mistakes. We are all just humans :) Love your products!